# Java - using radio buttons instead of tabs

Tags: java, radio-button, jpanel

I have an application that has some radio buttons on left side...

I'd like to have the pane/panel change depending on which radio button is selected... like when you have tabs at the top that choose which pane is displayed, however, I don't want to have the tabs visible at the top, I want the radio buttons to control the tabs function instead...

any idea how to do this?

Comment: Look at the `CardLayout`

Comment: Thanks! I think that will work I will  give it a try.

Comment: Is it possible to have the radio buttons on the left side of the application vertically with cardlayout?

Comment: Sure , you may use a `BorderLayout` for your main panel, put the buttons in a panel placed at `BorderLayout.WEST` and the panel with the `CardLayout`at `BorderLayout.CENTER` , for instance.

Comment: Are you aware that [a JTabbedPane can place its tabs on the left side](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setTabPlacement-int-) instead of on top?